# How to inject userscripts into embedded web page content?

Tags: javascript, events, dynamic, google-chrome-extension, user-defined-functions

I have a userscript I'd like to inject after clicking a link to open an embedded web page. Specifically, I'd like to know how I should go about injecting this script:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span')).filter(i => /(\d+)\spoint/.test(i.innerHTML)).forEach(i => i.style.display = 'none');

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div')).filter(i => /moreComments-/.test(i.id)).forEach(i => i.querySelector('p').click());

setTimeout(function() {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span')).filter(i => /(\d+)\spoint/.test(i.innerHTML)).forEach(i => i.style.display = 'none');
},7000)
```

Into all embeddable Reddit subpages, i.e. all linked threads loaded from a subreddit's main page:

[image]
*An image illustrating an embedded Reddit subpage in contrast to a standard fully-loaded page*

I assume this requires an event listener or `MutationObserver`, but I don't know how to go about specifying the solution. Reading the Reddit source is deeply confusing and I'm not a coder. This is just something I think would be useful to know for myself and other everyday web users.

**What are the right steps to follow in problem-solving a case like this? What kind of code should I consider?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to process the userscript on a selected group of page nodes. Because your code is only executed once per page load event, the nodes that load dynamically later on remain unaffected.

There are several ways to achieve your goal. One of the simplest approaches involves the use of the `setInterval` function. This calls your function periodically (by using a reasonable time span, say 500ms). With this function, you have to select the nodes you want and process only new arrival nodes. You can mark your node's DOM objects with something like the `_is_processed` property. And finally this can be wrapped into another function, say `doForEachOnce`. For example:

```
function doForEachOnce(list,theFunc) {
    list.forEach(i => {
        if (!i._is_processed) { i._is_processed = true; return theFunc(i); } else { return null; }
    });
}

doForEachOnce(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span')).filter(i => /(\d+)\spoint/.test(i.innerHTML)), i => i.style.display = 'none');
doForEachOnce(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div')).filter(i => /moreComments-/.test(i.id)), i => i.querySelector('p').click());

setInterval(function() {
  doForEachOnce(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span')).filter(i => /(\d+)\spoint/.test(i.innerHTML)), i => i.style.display = 'none');
},500);
```

I tested this userscript successfully with Tampermonkey. It expands all comments, hides the karma on page load, and then hides the karma again for each new arrival. Hope this is what you need.

Comment: Excellent approach, I believe. It works as expected and doesn't seem to have any performance issues. Thank you for this contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general, but I assume you asking something basic. If targeting some specific platform, please clarify your question.

I assume you want just inject javascript code into the web HTML page or part of HTML page.

Usually this done via script tag

```
    <script>
    /* Your code is here */
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll.......
    </script>
```

To force a link to call your code, you have to wrap your code inside function and format href attribute of a tag as javascript:func_name()

```
    <script>
    function my_func()
    {
      /* Your code is here */
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll.......
    }
    </script>
    <a href="javascript:my_func()">click me</a>
```

Comment: I use Tampermonkey to auto-inject the script into all Reddit pages. However, this only works for a single page load event. It doesn't work on the dynamically-loaded content like the embedded subpages. I'm not sure how to target the relevant link in order to re-apply the script after each embedded page load event.